# Python 2.7: Using a class's functions in another program/binding

Tags: python, class

Say I have a class ("Classname" which does, among other things, the following:

```
def price(self): return self.price
def number(self): return self.number
```

I have another function within that class that I would like to do the following: for each individual object within the class, multiply self.price by self.number, and add the sum of that to a variable to be used within a program.

```
def total(self,price,number):
   tot = 0
   for i in Classname:
       price = price(self)
       number = number(self)
       objvalue = price * number
       total += objvalue
   return total
```

Within the program that uses the Classname function, I'm struggling to use the 'total' function defined within the class. I just want the calcTotal function defined in the program to return the 'total' value defined by the function total within the class.

I've tried:

```
def calcTotal:
    totalhere = Classname.total()
```

which returns

```
"unbound method sumInventory() must be called with Classname instance as first argument (got nothing instead)"
```

so I then tried

```
totalhere = Classname.total(Classname)
```

which returns

```
"unbound method sumInventory() must be called with Classname instance as first argument (got type instance instead.)"
```

I'm not sure how to bind the method to return what I want it to return.

Comment: Your methods use attributes that *have the same name*. That means that `price` is either the method on the class or the attribute on the instance, never both.

Comment: Your sample code has other problems too, such as not defining a parameter list for the `calcTotal` function.

Comment: And `Classname` is not a function, it is class. But in `total()` you are using it as an iterable instead. If cannot make much sense of your question code, nor of what you are trying to achieve. Methods need an instance, so normally you'd use `self.price()` or `self.number()` or `instance = Classname(); `instance.price()`, etc.

Comment: By the sounds of "for each individual object within the class", it seems as if you're confusing classes with containers. Classes aren't naturally containers for all instances of themselves.

Comment: This is a mess man, this is a mess. Read a tutorial before you code.

Answer (score 0):

By the sounds of "for each individual object within the class", it seems as if you're confusing classes with containers. Classes aren't naturally containers for all instances of themselves.

I think you might want to use two separate classes, like this...

```
class Order(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._items = []

    def add_item(self, item):
        self._items.append(item)

    def get_total_price(self):
        total = 0
        for item in self._items:
            total += item.price() * item.quantity()
        return total


class OrderItem(object):

    def __init__(self, price, quantity):
        self._price = price
        self._quantity = quantity

    def price(self):
        return self._price

    def quantity(self):
        return self._quantity
```

...then you can do something like this...

```
>>> o = Order()
>>> o.add_item(OrderItem(1.99, 2))
>>> o.add_item(OrderItem(0.99, 5))
>>> print o.get_total_price()
8.93
```